# paper-action-dialog repositioning after dialog resize

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to trigger repositioning of a `paper-action-dialog` after dialog resize? When the dialog is resized, then the window is not centered anymore. Is there a way/function call to trigger repositioning of the dialog?
I've tried to set `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` to zero but this won't trigger repositioning.

When the user resizes the browser window, the `paper-action-dialog` is immediately centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the method called `resizeHandler`

Here is an example:

`this.$.IdOfYourDialog.resizeHandler();`

This is an inherited method from core-overlay.